# PHP directory rules of thumb?

Tags: php, dynamic, directory, filepath

I'm trying to make sure my file paths are as robust as they can be, and everyone knows that hard-coding paths can be disastrous in a lot of cases. Are there any general rules of thumb regarding referencing paths? Mostly concerning referencing above $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

I've been doing ../../(x100000), but it looks messy and was hoping there was a cleaner way.

Thanks

Comment: [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) can turn relative into absolute paths in case you're looking for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current directory of the running script I usually do:

```
str_replace('//', '/', str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__) . '/'));
```

This is a little bit hacky but it's reliable AFAIK.

But I think it will not work with Windows [UNC paths](http://www.uwplatt.edu/oit/terms/uncpath.html) (if you use them)...

Comment: @JamWaffles We want the path not the filename... __FILE__ contains the full path and filename of the file.

Comment: @Neal AFAIK a script can be in a directory and be executed another directory (current working directory != script directory).

Comment: @AlexV: Sorry, I meant `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: @AlexV: `basename(dirname(__FILE__))`... or just `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: This is the closest to what I ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

To get the current working directory: `getcwd();`

To get the currect directory name: `basename(getcwd());`

Answer (score 0):

Take a lesson from the Codeigniter framework (which handles relative paths notoriously well).

Take a look at the code in the index file:

> https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-reactor/blob/master/index.php

You can see that there are a variety of ways to handle this scenario (some better than others), but that file will show you the best practices.

Comment: Maybe highlighting the relevant bits in your answer would be useful.

Comment: Did you even look at the file? 90% of the code there is determining the appropriate paths. Disregard lines 31-47 & 201...

Comment: Of course, and I use CI on a daily basis. No need to get snippy, I just think your answer could be improved by pointing out the relevant parts instead of just deferring the solution elsewhere. OP is using relative paths, all the constants in the source you point to define absolute paths, by relativity to certain files or directories. Maybe highlight the methods used to define them, and how to use them in your application.